# Use of rem, em and px on image dimensions

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for some explanation regarding these units' use on image dimensions, but can't find any. I've read in some places to forget about pixels and use only rem/em, but I don't know if it's also applied for images dimensions (width/height).

For example, which one should I use in this case below?

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/NReN4xE.png" style="width: 5rem;" />5rem<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/NReN4xE.png" style="width: 5em;" />5em<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/NReN4xE.png" style="width: 100px;" />100px<br>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate as it asks for the use of rem, em and px on images (although similar) where that only covers two of the three units. A handy read nevertheless.

Comment: @NickZA you must not have read all the answers then.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. Potential duplicate but that answer is over explained.

Comment: Which one makes your image appear the way you want it to appear? Use that one.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I only found an answer about the image use and it's from 2015, 4 years ago. I'm asking because I don't know if anything has changed until now. Bootstrap, for example, started adopting `rem/em` instead of `px` 2 years ago.

Comment: @HereticMonkey you mean `px`? But isn't `rem/em` the same when "converting its size to px"? There might be a "deeper" explanation for its use.

Comment: @Luiz, have a look at my answer - hopefully it makes sense but at the end of the day, you are right: it is computed as `px` anyways. `em`/`rem` give you control of the size from different levels within the DOM (by changing the root element and all children change too). It's valuable in some cases but `px` is perfectly fine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `px` renders the pixel value
- `rem` uses the root element (`html`) using its `font-size` as the base (16px by default) to calculate its size, so basically your `rem` value from `img` multiplied by the `font-size` on `html`
- `em` uses the first parent with a `font-size` to calculate the size it needs to render (calculated the same as `rem` above - parent computed `px` value multiplied by your `em`). If a that parent is using `em` in its `font-size`, the child will use the computed/calculated `font-size` of the parent.

Explanation can be tough to grasp (especially `em`), have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/6ydf931w/

For the most part, I tend to avoid using `em` for almost everything because it can result in unexpected results if you are not permanently aware of where it is used.

I usually limit `rem` to text in the event it needs to be changed globally.

`px` is very predictable, if this works for you, there is no harm in using it.

Comment: `em` may be a bit confusing as I've explained, although it makes sense to me, refactoring welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

Many CSS properties take "length" values, such as width, margin, padding, font-size, etc.
Length is a number followed by a length unit, such as 10px, 2em, etc.

**`(px)`**The absolute length units are fixed and a length expressed in any of these will appear as exactly that size.
Absolute length units are not recommended for use on screen, because screen sizes vary so much. However, they can be used if the output medium is known, such as for print layout.

**`Relative length`** units specify a length relative to another length property. Relative length units scales better between different rendering mediums.
**`em`**    Relative to the font-size of the element 
**`rem`**   Relative to font-size of the root element

Use **REMs** for sizes and spacing.
Use **EMs** for media queries.

In summary, both **pixels** and **REMs** for media queries fail in various browsers when using browser zoom, and **`EMs`** are the best option we have.

Answer (score 2):

It's a better practice to use rem instead of pixels if you want a responsive website. This is because pixel is an absolute unit while rem is a unit relative to your root's font-size.

Imagine that you have all your elements in pixels and want to scale everything when your window is smaller. If you had pixels you would have to change everything one by one. However with rem you can change your root's font size and everything is scaled all at once.

Try changing the font size in the example below and see by yourself:

```css
html{
      font-size: 30px;
    }

.pixel1{
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.pixel2{
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: red;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.rem1{
      width: 1rem;
      height: 1rem;
      background-color: blue;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.rem2{
      width: 1.4rem;
      height: 1.4rem;
      background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="pixel1"></div>
<div class="pixel2"></div>
<div class="rem1"></div>
<div class="rem2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both **em** and **rem** are flexible, scalable units which are translated by the browser into pixel values, depending on the font size settings in your design. If you use a value of `1em or 1rem,` it could translate in the browser as anything from `16px to 160px` or any other value.

px values are used by the browser as is, so `1px` will always display as exactly `1px`.

Translation of rem units to pixel value is determined by the font size of the html element.

Translation of em units to pixel values is determined by the font size of the element they’re used on. Use `em units` for sizing that should scale depending on the font size of an element other than the root.Use `rem` units for sizing that doesn’t need `em` units, and that should scale depending on browser font size settings.Use rem units on `media queries`